# Joyroom JR-T04S mic not detected on Ubuntu 18.0

Tags: bluetooth, dell, realtek, headset

External Mic is not detected on Ubuntu 18.0

Codec: Realtek ALC3204
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
Laptop: Dell Latitude 3400

Internal mic working fine. When JR-T04S connected via bluetooth, input devices in sound setting doesn't show JR-T04S mic.

Works fine on windows.

Comment: Please check your details. Ubuntu *deb* based releases use a *year.month* format; so 18 represents 2018, and 0 represents the month of release - where 0 is no month??   Ubuntu had two releases in 2018; April & October; both have a 0 in them (04 or 10). Please clarify your product.   (Ubuntu also has specialist *year* format releases; they are different products, eg. Ubuntu Core 18 for the 2018 release of that product).

Comment: I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS to solve this but no luck. Kernel - 5.4.0-90-generic

Comment: The 5.4 kernel is the GA kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; and also the HWE kernel of 18.04.6; so upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 may have made no changes to kernel (thus kernel modules which are also known as *drivers*) if you were using the HWE stack of 18.04. FYI: the GA kernel of 18.04 was 4.15; but you weren't specific as to which you were using.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS however also has a HWE stack which will provide a later kernel (HWE of 20.04.3 is 5.11; 20.04.4 is 5.13).

Comment: Guiverc, how can i give this specific details? Any command?